# Automatically cd to a given remote path when connecting via ssh

Tags: ssh

I have a bunch of remote servers that I regularly connect to via ssh; which I've setup in my ~/.ssh/config file. I was wondering if it was possible to specify a remote path to cd to when I connect to some of these servers?

For example, I may have something like this in my config file:

```
Host testbox
HostName 192.123.456.789
User root
```

And when I ssh in to *testbox*, I'd like to also cd to */var/www/apps/myapp*.

I've had a look around but cannot see an option that would do that via the .ssh/config file.

Cheers,
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a tool I've open sourced that allows you to SSH and CD – aptly named [sshcd](https://github.com/christianbundy/sshcd). For the example you've given, you'd simply use:

```
sshcd root@testbox:/var/www/apps/myapp
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in the authorized_keys file.

Do a man on sshd, look under the heading "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT". You can add various options to each authorized key - one is command="command". As the manpage says, "Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for authentication."